# Formatting Rails/ERB HTML Output in Browser

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, seo

I have a Rails app which relies heavily on SEO and proper HTML formatting. As a result, being able to quickly view the source code of a generated (dynamic) page is essential to me.

Unfortunately, I am using a variety of gems like turbolinks which literally just throw their output into the page without any spacing or formatting whatsoever.

Currently if I view the source of my Rails application in a browser I get something like this:

```
<html>
<script1>
<script2>
<script3>
...
<script10>
<header>
</header>
<body>
  <markup></markup>
 <markup>
...
</markup>
  <markup>...</markup><markup></markup>
...
</html>
```

I understand that the HTML output generated by scripts and ERB is not incredibly important to search engines, but for my own optimization and data highlighting I would LOVE to see this formatted somehow.

Something like this is what I'm looking for:

```
<html>
  <script1>
  ...
  <script10>
<header>
  ...
</header>
<body>
  <markup>
    ...
  </markup>
</body>
</html>
```

The only gem I have found designed to format the *output html* rather than the *source-code html* is rails-tidy. Rails-tidy hasn't been updated in many years (7yrs), and seems to be very buggy in Rails 4.2 alongside all of my code.

What are my alternatives for prettyfying the HTML output of my rails app in the browser?

Comment: Use Firebug or the browser debug tool of your choice?

Comment: Instead of trying to format the output html, why not just use the browser's developer tools for this? You can easily inspect your page (e.g. right click -> inspect element in Firefox and Chrome) and there you have formatted html with syntax highlighting.

Comment: These are both valid answers, however I was hoping it would be possible to format the output. I'm trying to ensure my website is as over-optimized as possible, and some of the tools I've written are based on markup structure: a single div not closed could break them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Rack middleware](http://rack.github.io/) for that. I've searched and didn't find any, but there is one to [prettyfyJSON](https://github.com/damien/rack-pretty_json) that you can almost copy.

You can read more about [rack and rails here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html).

---

#### Update

There are some already done [gems](https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=rack+tidy) to do this.